# Mean Value Property for Harmonic Functions (clarifying Axler's proof)

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm going through Axler's proof of the mean value property, and I'm a little puzzled. Since this proof is in the first few pages of his book, I thought I'd ask for clarification before going further into the book.

He begins by fixing $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and defining $\Omega = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} : \epsilon < |x| < 1\}$. Letting $u(x)$ be harmonic and $v(x) = |x|^{2-n}$, he says we should apply Green's identity under these conditions. Recall Green's identity is:

$$\int_{\Omega} (u \,\Delta{v} - v\, \Delta{u})\,dV = \int_{\partial\Omega} (u \,\nabla{v} - v \,\nabla{u})\,ds$$

From this he deduces that

$$0 = (2-n) \int_S u\, ds - (2-n)\epsilon^{1-n} \int_{\epsilon S} u\, ds - \int_S \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \, ds -\epsilon^{2-n} \int_{\epsilon S} \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \, ds.$$

but I don't see how to actually compute this. I've tried it myself, but there's obviously something I am missing. For instance, he has 4 terms, but I would figure there'd only be 3 since $|x|^{2-n} \Delta{u} = 0$ since $u$ is harmonic.

Other than being mystified by the computation, I'm not sure what he means by $\epsilon{S}$. Here, $S$ refers to $S^{n-1}$, but I'm not sure that $\epsilon{S}$ represents. How does it even come about?

Comment: $\epsilon S$ is the circle with radius $\epsilon$. It enters, because the domain $\Omega$ on which Green's theorem is applied has two "boundary parts", the inner ($\epsilon S$) and the outer ($S^{n-1}$) boundary.

Comment: That makes sense. Would you happen to know why the left-hand side is zero? I get that $v \Delta{u} = 0$ by assumption of $u$ being harmonic, but how then do you get that the integral of $u \Delta{v}$ over $\Omega$ is zero?

Comment: Because $v$ is also harmonic on $\Omega$ (for $n>2$. For $n=2$, you have to use a slightly different $v$ iirc). Evans probably showed this in an example (?). Otherwise, this is claimed here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function (just before "remarks"). The calculation showing this should not be too hard.

Comment: I'm sure that Axler shows this somewhere: If $F(x)=f(|x|)$, then $\Delta F = f''(|x|)+\frac{(n-1)}{|x|}f'(|x|)$ for $n \ge 2$. This gives $\Delta |x|^{2-n}=0$ for $n \ge 3$ whenever $x \ne 0$.